# Ruby agent.click page.links.text iframe interrupts

Tags: ruby, linux, sms, mechanize

I dont know if the title is appropriate but i expect some help. I was searching for a way to send sms using Linux terminal and I found a script. The script is in Ruby, and looks good. I am not familiar with Ruby but the code is well explained so that an average can use it easily.

```
require 'mechanize'
number   = ARGV.shift
message  = ARGV * " "

if message.length > 160 || message.length < 1
  $stderr.puts "Message too short or too long.."
  exit 1
end

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.xxxxxx.com/')
hp_formlogin = page.form('login')
hp_formlogin.username = 'xxxxxxxx'
hp_formlogin.pass = 'xxxxxxxx'
page = agent.submit(hp_formlogin)

#ONLY USED IF YOUR SITE REDIRECTS YOU AFTER LOGIN
page = agent.click page.links.text('Send Free SMS')
pp page

page = agent.get('http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/send/free-sms')
#ONLY USED IF THERE'S NO NAME FOR THE FORMFIELD.
# SO IF YOU HAVE ONE, COMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW AND ENTER THIS
 hp_formsms = page.form('freesms2')
#hp_formsms = page.forms.first
hp_formsms.frno = number
hp_formsms.message3 = message
page = agent.submit(hp_formsms)
```

This is the code... But the issue is that, on login into the site, It shows an intermediate frame(iframe I think) before getting into the profile. So that the page = agent.click page.links.text('Send Free SMS') is not working. This is because, this frame does not have a link named send free sms. This have a close button made from an image. How can I get into the profile page bypassing this frame and send message. 
Please help.. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get frame by frame_with, iframe_with and the other.
Example:

```
page.frame_with(:src => %rfoo/).click
```

Please see the following document.
http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html